# How did the values 97 & 123 come?

Tags: php

I am a beginner learning PHP. I was going through a post in Stackoverflow where an alphabet is shifted by 4 characters and the result is displayed.

This is the code :

```
<?php

    $code = 'string';

    $str = $code;
    $length = strlen($str);
    $result = '';
    $n = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i){
        $c = ord($str[$i]);
        if (97 <= $c && $c < 123) {                 
            $result.= chr(($c + $n + 7) % 26 + 97); 
        } else if(65 <= $c && $c < 91) {            
            $result.= chr(($c + $n + 13) % 26 + 65);
        } else {
            $result.= $str[$i];
        }
    }
    echo $result;

?>
```

However, I didn't understand the logic completely. How did values 97 and 123 come? 
Assistance appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What does `var_dump($code);` output?

Comment: This looks to be the implementation of a Caesar cipher.

Answer (score 3):

97 and 123 are the ASCII values of the characters `a` and `{`, respectively.

The character `{` is one past `z`, which is 122.

Thus, the if statement `if (97 <= $c && $c < 123)` is checking that the character `$c` is a lowercase letter.

Similarly, `else if(65 <= $c && $c < 91)` checks that `$c` is an uppercase letter.

See [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Note that the intent of this code could be made a lot clearer by comparing characters instead of ASCII values:

```
<?php
$str="$code";
$length=strlen($str);
$result = "";
$n=5;
$n=$n-1;

$lowercase = ord('a');
$uppercase = ord('A');
for($i = 0, $l = strlen($str); $i < $l; ++$i)
{
    $c = $str[$i];
    $o = ord($c);
    if ('a' <= $c && $c <= 'z') {
        $result.= chr(($o + $n + 7) % 26 + $lowercase);
    } else if('A' <= $c && $c <= 'Z') {
        $result.= chr(($o + $n + 13) % 26 + $uppercase);
    } else {
       $result.= $str[$i];
    }
}
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but one doubt.., http://nandu.rohithz.com/test.php this is the page I created to test the script live. 

Even if I type the text "Hello World", it renders "Lipps Asvph" (L and A is captial) Which function is performing this and how is the space character also being echoed perfectly?

Comment: The loop shifts the `i`th character at every iteration. I don't know what you mean by "which function" -- could you please clarify? The `else` handles the space, which has ASCII value 32.

Comment: Right, the loop is appending each character to `$result` after possibly shifting it. Notice that due to the `if-elseif-else`, only alphabetical characters are shifted. Other characters, including spaces, are not changed. After the loop, it echoes `$result`. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Its checking that the character is between `a` and `b` on the ASCII table.
http://www.asciitable.com/

The `ord` function takes a string and returns the unsigned binary value of the first (or only) byte.  On the ASCII table these values can be represented as characters.

After it completes processing, that snippet of code converts the byte value back to a character with `chr`.

Answer (score 0):

The `chr` function takes an integer and returns the ASCII character represented by that integer. It turns out that the character associated with 97 is `a` and that associated with 122 is `z` so all this is doing is determining whether the character is a lowercase alphabet character, i.e. `a-z`.

You can look at the ASCII codes [here](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)